# Display results "nicely" from a sparql query

Tags: java, jsp, rdf, sparql

Hey I'm having a problem trying to display the results on a "nice" format.

I have the following code:

```
                try {
        //opening owl file
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Karen/Desktop/Proyecto/bbdd.owl"), null, "TTL");
        //System.out.println(model);

        //create a new query
        String queryString
                 ="PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"
                +"PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"
                +"PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
                +"PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"         
                +"PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>"
                +"SELECT reduced ?r WHERE { "
                +"  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta . "
                +"  ?x rdfs:label ?r."
                +"  filter not exists {"
                +"      ?x rec:Ingrediente ?i "
                + "filter(?i not in " + convertToSPARQLListQuery1(ing) + ")"
                +"}"
                +"}";
        System.out.println(queryString);
        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query q = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        //print query results
         while (results.hasNext()) {
            //System.out.println(results.getResourceModel());
            //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out,results, q);
            list.add(results.next());
        }

    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Query Failed !" + e);
    }
```

And a very simple JSP. The fact is that when I try to display the results of that query I have the following format:

[image]

I would like to print exactly those receipes but without the ("?r = ...) I only want the name of the receipe and the amount of ingredients without all the rest. 
In this example I would like to print: 
Prueba3

Prueba3 1

Prueba 2

Prueba4 4

etc..

Comment: You can't rely on the toString operation of a result set if you want control.  So you need to replace your output code with `QuerySolution qs = results.next(); ` then use query solution operations to access th value of variable `r'.

Comment: Sorry I don´t understand, I have no output code, Im saving it into a list, but I would like to change the format before I save it into the list.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip. I have the solution:

```
   public static List getAllReceipes(){
    List list = new ArrayList();

    String log4jConfPath = "C:/Users/Karen/workspace/Jena/src/Tutorial/log4j.properties";
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
    try {
        //opening owl file
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Karen/Desktop/Proyecto/bbdd.owl"), null, "TTL");
        //System.out.println(model);

        //create a new query
        String queryString
                = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
                + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"
                + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
                + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"
                + "PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>"
                + "SELECT ?r ?i WHERE { "
                + "  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta ."
                + "  ?x rdfs:label ?r."
                + " ?x rec:Ingrediente ?i."
                + "}";

        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query q = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

        //execute the query and obtain results
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        //print query results
        while (results.hasNext()) {

            //System.out.println(results.getResourceModel());
            //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out,results, q);
            QuerySolution qs = results.next();
            list.add(qs.getLiteral("r")); 
        }
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Query Failed !");
    }
    System.out.println("size: " + list.size());
        return list;      
}
```

as easy as that one!